# Разбивка номерных емкостей мобильной нумерации на диапазоны

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть две границы номерной ёмкости, например:

ОТ: 7902125000 -  ДО : 7902129999

И необходимо вытащить диапазоны в формате:
7902125*
7902126*
7902127*
7902128*
7902129*

(и отдельные номера, если по ним нельзя выстроить диапазон номеров)

Есть сложности в том, что границы могут быть примерно такими:

ОТ: 7902125009 -  ДО : 7902125023 из которого можно выделить только один диапазон  790212501* и отдельные номера: 7902125009, 7902125020 , 7902125021 , 7902125022, 7902125023

Как это можно на питоне реализовать?

Comment: Откуда вытащить? Есть таблица доступных номеров? Складывается ощущение, что вы пытаетесь совместить две сущности. Разбивку номеров на диапазоны нужного размера и список номеров в наличии. Может всё же разделить эти вещи? А если вы хотите представить номера в надичии в виде диапазонов, то отдельный номер можно представить в виде диапазона. Надо брать диапазоны a <= x < b. Соответственно отдельный номер это например диапазон 7902125009 - 7902125010

Comment: Откуда берутся такие странные границы? Что за алгоритм? вы сами свой вопрос перечитайте.

Comment: Есть таблица доступных интервалов номеров (принадлежащих определенному оператору и региону), т.е. по примеру выше 5000 номеров, и необходимо их разделить на диапазоны охватывающие все номера (по примеру выше 7902125* 7902126* 7902127* 7902128*)

Comment: по "Странным" границам ответил выше - границы номеров принадлежащих определенному оператору и региону

Comment: Ну в рамках одного региона при этом может быть много диапазонов, судя по тому, что вы описали. Ну вот идете по списку. Если разность между номерами больше 1, то закрываете один диапазон, начинаете новый.

Comment: А как отдельные номера вытащить? Не следует ли вначале создать полный кортеж всех номеров, а затем со схожими преобразовывать их к нужному виду?

Comment: Возможно я так до конца и не понял что нужно. Лучше если вы покажите пример входных данных и пример того, что будет в итоге. Как именно вы хотите хранить результат. Я , как и писал, сделал бы две сущности. Диапазоны номеров регионов и отдельно список доступных номеров.

Comment: Данные по границам хранятся в экселевской табличке, граница А, граница Б, пример входных данных: FROM    -  73512782999   ||||  TO     -   73512781800    |||||   LEN    -  1200  |||||   GLOBCARRIER      -    ООО Т2 Мобайл  |||     BRANCH   - г. Челябинск      |||||     RANGE   -  735127818*, 73512782*
Т.е. Вводим два номера: From и TO, на выходе получаем RANGE

Comment: Не знаю как понятнее сформулировать, наверное наименьшее количество диапазонов охватывающее весь список по двум границам номеров

Comment: что у вас на выходе должно получиться для таких границ ОТ: 7902125009 - ДО : 7902125123 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал такой алгоритм:

1. Ищем числа с нулями в конце и записываем их в таком формате: `(число, кол-во нулей на конце)`
2. Сортируем по убыванию количества нулей и по возрастанию самого числа. `(-x[1], x[0])`
3. Для каждой пары проверяем входит ли диапазон `range(число, число+10**кол-во нулей)` в исходный диапазон.
4. Если входит - вычитаем из общего диапазона и добавляем в список масок `str(num)[:-zeros]+'*'`.
5. После проверки всех пар `(число, кол-во нулей на конце)` остаются числа, для которых маска не "придумалась".

Получился такой код:

```
start = 7902125009
end = 7902125023

masks = []

def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
    return len(str(num)) - len(str(num).rstrip('0'))

all_range = set(range(start, end+1))

num_zeros = []
for n in all_range: # pairs (num, tail_zeros)
    z = end_zeros(n)
    if z:
        num_zeros.append((n, z))
    
num_zeros.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])) # tail_zeros ASC, num DESC

for num, zeros in num_zeros:
    tmp_range = set(range(num, num+10**zeros))
    if tmp_range.issubset(all_range): # if range(num, num+10**zeros) in all_range
        all_range -= tmp_range # substract from all_range
        masks.append(str(num)[:-zeros]+'*') # adding mask to list of masks

for n in all_range: # no mathcing masks
    masks.append(str(n))

print(masks)
```

UPD:

```
start = 73519000000
end   = 73519099999

masks = []

def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
    return len(str(num)) - len(str(num).rstrip('0'))

all_range = set(range(start, end+1))

num_zeros = []
for n in all_range: # pairs (num, tail_zeros)
    z = end_zeros(n)
    if z:
        num_zeros.append((n, z))
    
num_zeros.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])) # tail_zeros ASC, num DESC

for num, _zeros in num_zeros:
    for zeros in reversed(range(1, _zeros+1)): # decr tail zeros
        tmp_range = set(range(num, num+10**zeros))
        if tmp_range.issubset(all_range): # if range(num, num+10**zeros) in all_range
            all_range -= tmp_range # substract from all_range
            masks.append(str(num)[:-zeros]+'*') # adding mask to list of masks
    
for n in all_range: # no mathcing masks
    masks.append(str(n))

print(masks)
```

Comment: Очень интересное решение, спасибо!) Но к сожалению не всегда верно отрабатывает, например: start = 73519000000. end = 73519099999. Где по итогу можно обойтись: 735190*, а код отрабатывает: ['7351901*', '7351902*', '7351903*', '7351904*', '7351905*', '7351906*', '7351907*', '7351908*', '7351909*', '73519001*', '73519002*', '73519003*', '73519004*', '73519005*', '73519006*', '73519007*', '73519008*', '73519009*', '735190001*', '735190002*', '735190003*', '735190004*', '735190005*', '735190006*', '735190007*', '735190008*', '735190009*', '7351900001*', '7351900002*', '7351900003*', и т.д]

Comment: @kovshar22 посмотрите UPD.

Comment: Все работает, огромное вам спасибо))

Answer (score 2):

```
def ranges( first:str, last:str ):
    assert( len(first) == len(last) )
    assert( int(first) <= int(last) )

    if first == last:
        return [first]
    if first == "0" * len(first) and last== "9"* len(last):
        return ["*"]
    if first[0] == last[0]:
        return [ first[0]+v  for v in ranges( first[1:], last[1:] ) ]

    assert( int(first[0]) < int(last[0]) )
    return ranges( first, first[0] + "9"*(len(first)-1) ) \
        + ranges( str(int(first[0])+1) + "0"*(len(first)-1), last  )
```

1. если начало диапазона совпадает с концом - то решение единственное (без маски).
2. если начало диапазона состоит из одних нулей, а конец из девяток - то решение "*"
3. если первая цифра начала, совпадает с первой цифрой конца, то отбросим первую цифру, и решим задачу для урезанный диапазонов. (Потом припишем первую цифру к результату.)
4. если первая цифра начала, меньше чем первая цифра конца - разделим задачу на две, введя промежуточную точку: первая цифра диапазона + нужное количество девяток. (Следующее число за промежуточной точкой + первая цифра +1, и нули.)

test:

```
assert ranges( "7351900000" , "7902125023" ) == ['73519*', '7352*', '7353*', '7354*', '7355*', '7356*', '7357*', '7358*', '7359*', '736*', '737*', '738*', '739*', '74*', '75*', '76*', '77*', '78*', '7900*', '7901*', '79020*', '790210*', '790211*', '7902120*', '7902121*', '7902122*', '7902123*', '7902124*', '790212500*', '790212501*', '7902125020', '7902125021', '7902125022', '7902125023']
assert ranges( "7902125000" , "7902129999" ) == ['7902125*', '7902126*', '7902127*', '7902128*', '7902129*']
```

Comment: Все работает, тоже очень интересное решение и отрабатывает быстрее, чем вариант ниже. Огромное спасибо)